# Firebase - How to convert UTC timestamp to UTC-5?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building an app to do documentation for research. One of the utilities I'm building is counters to keep track of certain experiments.

Right now, this function works, but the only issue I have is the fact that the timing is not accurate. When I set a new counter, I get a +1 day +1 hour offset on positive (T+) counters, while negative (T-) counters are exact.

How do I convert the firebase timestamp to a local timezone so it is usable?

This is the code:

```
    const now = new Date().getTime();      
    const distance = date - now;

    const days = Math.abs(Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)));
    const hours = Math.abs(Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)));
    const minutes = Math.abs(Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)));
    const seconds = Math.abs(Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The offset in the positive counter is generated by the way the math is done.

By changing `const distance = date - now;` to `const distance = now - date;` it gets fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The Firebase/Google SDKs don't provide any way to localize a timestamp.  That's entirely up to you to do.

Timestamps (like JavaScript Date objects) are always represented internally in UTC. What you can do is use the [toDate()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#todate) method on a timestamp object to convert it into a Date object.  After that, you have any number of options to format that into something that contains your desired timezone.  momentjs is commonly used for that.

Again, to be clear, converting both to and from timezone-formatted strings is the application's responsibilty.  Firestore's responsibility is to just load and store that moment in time in a field in a document, and it does that using UTC representation, which is common across all major operating systems.